# Using Eigenfaces for 1:1 Authentication

Tags: face-recognition, eigenvector

I am currently working on a small project which uses facial features for authentication. The input face will be matched with only one persons face(the face used for setup). So:

1. When setting up the users face should i put random peoples faces to create the eigenface subspace? Or should it just be the users image with different expressions, lighting etc.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Eigenfaces for 1:1 Authentication.  Eigenfaces is used for face identification, not face authentication.  So you'll need to find another algorithm, for example LBP, PEM, ...